# How to set auto update .js module route after run server

Tags: node.js, express, module

node server.js
server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes_module = require('./routes/routes.js');
app.use(routes_module);  

module.exports = app;
var server = app.listen(process.env.port || 8081 ,function(req, res)
{
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('PHPExpress app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

i want to update automatic when edit code in middleware and save in the moment server running.
routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express();
router.use('/api/edit', require('./api/edit.js'));
router.use('/api/select', require('./api/select.js'));
router.use('/api/insert', require('./api/insert.js'));
router.use('/api/delete', require('./api/delete.js'));
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please clarify more what you want to do.

Comment: update about  edit code in middleware and save in the moment server running.

Comment: You mean you don't want to stop the server every time you edit the code ?

Comment: yes i want add or edit api

Comment: did the answer work with you ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To restart the server automatically after updating the code:

**1)** In the terminal install `nodemon` globally:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

**2)** Instead of `node` write `nodemon` in the `start script` in your project's package.json file:

```
"start": "nodemon app.js"
```

**3)** `npm start`